# Build failed when signing apk

Tags: android, apk, codenameone

I've a build error when I set the certificate fields, also reading the [Error Log](https://pastebin.com/y1H01Vje) I can't find the point, what I'm missing.

With blank certificate fields everything works fine and I get my apk.

Here my builds params

```
ios.locationUsageDescription=Some functionality of the application depends on your location
ios.objC=true
ios.project_type=ios
win.ver=8
android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/><uses-feature         android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"         android:required="true"/>
ios.dsym=false
android.xapplication=<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
ios.glAppDelegateHeader=
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"
ios.add_libs=SystemConfiguration.framework
ios.statusbar_hidden=false
ios.application_exits=false
ios.includePush=false
android.playService.maps=true
android.GoogleMaps.minPlayServicesVersion=9.4.0
j2me.nativeThemeConst=0
java.version=8
ios.pods=,GoogleMaps
ios.prerendered_icon=false
ios.testFlight=false
rim.obfuscation=false
ios.interface_orientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
ios.newStorageLocation=true
android.release=true
ios.pods.platform=,7.0
android.debug=true
ios.pods.sources=,https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
```

Can you give me a hint or some link to read?
Thank's, Davide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build failed because of below `proguard` warnings :

```
Warning: net.amicofree.fdrmobile.cno.forms.BarCodeForm: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfiguration
Warning: net.amicofree.fdrmobile.cno.forms.BarCodeForm: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfiguration
Warning: net.amicofree.fdrmobile.cno.forms.BarCodeForm: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfiguration
Warning: net.amicofree.fdrmobile.cno.forms.BarCodeForm: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfiguration
Warning: net.amicofree.fdrmobile.cno.forms.BarCodeForm: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfiguration
Warning: net.amicofree.fdrmobile.cno.forms.BarCodeForm: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfiguration
Warning: net.amicofree.fdrmobile.cno.forms.BarCodeForm: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfiguration
Warning: net.amicofree.fdrmobile.cno.forms.BarCodeForm: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfiguration
Warning: net.amicofree.fdrmobile.cno.forms.BarCodeForm: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfiguration
```

If you think that the referenced class exist in your compiled and build project, you can add below line to your `proguard` rules to supress these warnings:

```
-dontwarn net.amicofree.fdrmobile.cno. forms.**
```

Comment: First of all thank's to point me in the right direction, I've removed the  "BarCodeForm" and everything compiles and the app works also installed on the device. But a part of the question is still open: why it happens only when signing the app and doesen't happens always?

Comment: On Android we don't recompile your code so if you used API's that aren't supported we can't really tell until the obfuscation stage (not the signing stage). The question is how did you use the barcode scanning and which barcode scanning solution? Did you use one of our existing solutions for barcodes? If you changed the classpath of your Codename One project then the server build process is just unaware of this and won't know what to do.

Comment: @DavideRizzo You are very welcome! As "Shai Almog" has already answered your question, I won't say much. I will point out that when you put `minifyEnabled true` in your `build.gradle` you ask for minimizing your code by removing unused libraries and codes, so `proguard` will check your compiled code to see which codes are unused to be removed and that's why you see this in this case and not before it.

Comment: So if I ask for a release build  I use, for default,  minifyEnabled=true, and this is why I had the error build. -- The BarCodeForm class was one of the first clasess I wrote, I' will rethink it and write it again. Thank's to all.